# Joda LocalTime.now().getHoursOfDay() starting 6 hours later?

Tags: android, jodatime

I have the following code:

```
  int t1 = (LocalTime.now().getHourOfDay());
```

In my variable I'm getting the wrong number of hours. It seems that java joda is starting from 6AM instead of 00:00 and not adding the 6 hours till 06:00AM. My system time is correctly set and web updated therefore I do not see any omission concerning that. I've read the documentation but I'm afraid I can't find the answer there. I can easily add +6

```
   int t1 = (LocalTime.now().getHourOfDay())+6;
```

But this will affect the Phone devices once uploaded on the appstore. Any idea on that?

Comment: Do you happen to be in a time-zone which is 6 hours different to UTC?

Comment: If your system is correctly set, as you're saying, then I think that if you call Time.getTime(), you should receive the correct time.

Comment: Which class is the "Time" from?

Answer (score 1):

your java timezone was not set properly.
try to set it or set it programmatically with ZoneId:
`int t1 = (LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Almaty")).getHour());`